# How to use function from self defined prototype - object.create

Tags: javascript

I'm using object.create to create an object, based on a prototype I created.

This is the prototype

```
var employeePrototype = {
            calulateTax: function() {
                console.log(salary * taxRate);
            }
        };
```

This is the object I created.

```
var jack = Object.create(employeePrototype);
        jack.salary = 25000;
        jack.taxRate = .40;
        jack.calulateTax();
```

When I call jack.calculateTax, I get the following error

index.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: salary is not defined
    at Object.calulateTax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `this` to use the `salary` and `taxRate` of the instance

```js
var employeePrototype = {
  calulateTax: function() {
    console.log(this.salary * this.taxRate);
  }
};

var jack = Object.create(employeePrototype);
jack.salary = 25000;
jack.taxRate = .40;
jack.calulateTax();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), it's a lot more orthodox to use a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class). Here's how you'd accomplish it using one:

```js
class Employee {
  salary = 25000;
  taxRate = .40;

  calulateTax () {
    console.log(this.salary * this.taxRate);
  }
}

const jack = new Employee();

jack.calulateTax();
```

The class fields are part of [TC39/proposal-class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations), which is in stage 3, but is already part of [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6001727933251584), [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1529758), and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.0.0/), or can be transpiled using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0#tc39-proposals-https-githubcom-tc39-proposals-support).

For ES2015 support, you can simply move the initialization into the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor):

```js
class Employee {
  constructor () {
    this.salary = 25000;
    this.taxRate = .40;
  }

  calulateTax () {
    console.log(this.salary * this.taxRate);
  }
}

const jack = new Employee();

jack.calulateTax();
```

Comment: Thank you, and I appreciate it. I'm just going through a course atm, so this is how they do it. ES6 and stuff is coming up soon.